# Find equation for solution of differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Please help me to solve this problem:

Differential equation $y''+p(x)y=0$ has nonzero solution $f(x)$. Find the equation for function $z(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$.

My ideas:

I only see that $z(x) = \ln(y(x))'$. I tried to express this function in terms of $p(x)$, but failed.

Can you please help me with the problem?
Thanks a lot!

Update:
After the hint given by A.Γ. it was trivial to show that required equation is $z'+z^2+p=0$.
Thanks a lot for your help, A.Γ.!

Comment: NB: $z=(\ln y)'\not=\ln y$.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for pointing out this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: If $f'=z\cdot f$ then $f''=z'\cdot f+z\cdot f'=z'\cdot f+z^2\cdot f$ then
$$
0=f''+p\cdot f=\ldots
$$

Comment: Thanks, it was so easy, I feel myself dumb for not seeing it.